# Querying a DynamoDB with Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

When querying a DynamoDB table, the code works fine for a valid entry (msisdn) however, for non-existent entries it does crash.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('PhoneList')

# Phone Number 
# -> Existent: 44790000000
msisdn = 44790000000

try:
    response = table.get_item(Key={'MSISDN': msisdn})
    
    name = response['Item']['Name']
    ID = str(response['Item']['ID'])
    birth = response['Item']['Birth']
    
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    print("Phone number not found")
    exit(-1)

print("Phone:", msisdn)
print("Name:", name)
print("ID:", id)
print("Birth:", birth)
```

**Invalid Entry**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dyn.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = response['Item']['Name']
KeyError: 'Item'
```

**Database**

[image]

I think I might not handled correctly the Exception?

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.get_item)

> If there is no matching item, GetItem does not return any data and there will be no Item element in the response.

so you need to catch KeyError instead of ClientError.